# Displaying two columns of a CardView in a LinearLayout

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I am trying to fetch 3 sets of objects from my database and I want to display them in a fashion like this:

[image]

but it's putting them only in one place rather than spreading out, see here:

[image]

I am guessing that the cardviews are overlapping each other and staying all in one place rather than going the available area.

I am using LinearLayout for the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_addimage"
                    android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />'
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item name"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/itemName"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/itemPrice"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This looks like a single `CardView`. Are you placing it in another layout that will allow you to replicate this `CardView` to show multiple cards? See [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) for an example.

Comment: Also consider uploading screenshots directly to Stack Overflow, as they will be then hosted on Stack Overflow's Imgur Pro account which ensures images are not lost. See [official announcement here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) and [this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/310976).

Answer (score 6):

You can not do that from XML side, you have to do that when you load items from adapter with using `gridlayoutmanager` like this

In Fragment:

```
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that from xml side, you have to do that when you load items from adaptor with using gridlayoutmanager like this

```
 mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried this code to get the cardviews

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#999"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        android:elevation="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:text="Dance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="38dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"

           />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
        android:text="10:30  60min"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        android:text="There are many forms of dance from
ball room tobarn dancing and disco to
moris dancing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_subtitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_description"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/left">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trainer_title"
                android:text="Associated trainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_trainer_title"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/image_circle"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/right">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trainer_price"
                android:text="£5 only"
                android:textSize="28dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="116dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                 />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_book_now"
                android:background="@drawable/image_roundedcorner"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Book now"
                android:textStyle="normal"

                android:textSize="18dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```